# Duplicate Data In Slow Changing Dimension-type-2 Using Merge Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a data like below, and I am trying to implement a slow changing dimension -2

```
 DECLARE @MYTABLE TABLE
    (
       LocalID INT,
       STDID INT,
       MYDATE DATE,
       SKU VARCHAR(100),
       LOCALPRICE DECIMAL(8,2)
    )

INSERT INTO @MYTABLE
    SELECT 1000004, 1038, '2017-10-17',34106860642, 5215 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1000004, 1038, '2017-10-17',34106860642, 5648 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1000004, 1038, '2017-10-17',34106860642, 5615 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1000004, 1038, '2017-10-17',34106860642, 5901
```

but the issue with data is: there is a duplicate when creating a key which is a combination of

```
LocalID, STDID, and SKU
```

Due to duplicate in the key **columns** merge statement is generating error.

How to handle such kind of data while implementing **SCD-TYPE 2**?

Comment: What do you want to have happen instead of an error?   What is your desired result?

Comment: @TabAlleman: if any change to the price it should create a new row with status column value as 1 for active row, and old row status change to 0

Comment: How do you know which row is the new row and which is the old row?   What do you order by?

Answer (score 0):

Slowly changing dimension of type 2 is when you keep the previous states of the dimension AND the new state. In order to do that you MUST have a column that separates them from each other (key column). So you can either add a column to the dimension table for ID and not use the combination that you are using.  Or add an extra column like version or validity date or something like that and also include that column in the key. Depending on your needs you can use version column with values like 1,2,3,4 or a Valid-to-date column ( here you can see when the change happened) or a Current column set to 1 and the others set to 0 (but again you will have duplicates if the key is based only on that)

Comment: how if we will add row_number and used it for key 
something like ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Localid,STDID,SKU ORDER BY Localid) AS row_number
NOT Sure whether it will work

Comment: I don't have sql server currently installed to test the exact syntax but in my experience the easiest solution is  to have a primary int key for each row of the dimension. Then in the fact you reference that key and when you build the datamart you join on the other fields and the version for example. I mean instead of row_number just add one column DIMENSION_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY